# Build Version for simple C++ applications in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, build

I'm working on hundreds of projects written in cpp.
These projects are almost the same, each exe is some kind of translator. It's all inside kind of applications.
In these projects there are only one cpp which are being changed and non-changable StdAfx.h/cpp files, but not standard ones.
We, as team of programmers, change these projects often.
Also we compile it to different version of our software. At the time there are like 800 different projects, from 3-5 different versions.

I would like to add some basic information about the build like date and author and hopefully version we compile to. I tried http://autobuildversion.codeplex.com/ but I was unable to get any build versions.

I cannot add any additional files to the project (company policy, don't ask...), I cannot change anything by hand (too much work), I cannot add anything regarding that matter to existing cpp's, so only thing I can use (or at least I can think of) is add-in with that functionality.
My second idea would be to use different (compiled along with the project) stub with that information.

Do you have any working solution I can use? Or any ideas?

Comment: The company of course has bigger issues that need fixing first, but the sane approach here would be a data-driven translator.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a version resource to the executable compilation. That version resource file can be auto-generated, or can #include another small auto-generated file that includes the version of your product. Once the executable has the version resource, you can check the version just by right-clicking in explorer and go to the file properties.

If you can't add any files to the project then that's going to be problem but you can circumvent the issue by writing a script or a program that adds the version resource to the executable post-compilation using `UpdateResource()`

Your work place sounds like a fun place to work at...

Comment: I don't complain about my work place :) There's no hurry in anything, nobody is screaming, no dead lines etc... I just need to stick with some policies they came up some years ago. Going back to the issue - that's what I thought, I would need to write my own extension if I want it. Anyway thanks for the answer.